# The OAuth prompt doesn't go away after the permission is given to the bot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

The OAuth prompt doesn't go away after the permission is given to the bot. This prompt keeps showing even after the user has given the permissions.

[Prompt message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaXmw.png)

And when clicked on continue this error comes up .

[Error after clicking continue in prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvr15.png)

Please help me out.

Once the permissions are given the prompt should go away but it is not going in this case.

Comment: Could you please share the repro steps to try at our end?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT , I just cloned the repo from here and changed the manifest and appsettings as suggested https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-teams-authentication/csharp  , and the login works fine and user is being authenticated . But when I go to another chat and come back to the bot the prompt comes up again even though I have already given the consent to to prompt .

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT 
This is my OAuthPromptSettings
`AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
                nameof(OAuthPrompt),
                new OAuthPromptSettings
                {
                    ConnectionName = ConnectionName,
                    Text = "Please sign in to get started",
                    Title = "Sign In",
                    Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login (1000 * 60 * 5)
                    EndOnInvalidMessage = true
                }));`

Comment: We have tested this and facing same issue when user don't have profile photo. When user has profile photo then the popup is going. Could you please test this with user who have profile photo and confirm this?

Comment: Hi @Nivedipa-MSFT , have tested with both with and without profile photo accounts but the issue is common in both

Comment: Tested again but it's not reproducing now. Please refer below video: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/92150070/210254389-2088b891-651a-4a5a-8ef7-336727c49a14.mp4

Comment: Hi @Nivedipa-MSFT , can you please share the repo of the code if possible ? Or https://github.com/thashu0424/TeamSSO can you check this demo manifest if the issues is there on your end

Comment: We have tested this using below sample and followed the readme files for steps.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-teams-authentication/csharp

Comment: Hello @ThashwinY - Hope your issues has been resolved with provided suggestions.

Comment: Hi @ChetanSharma-msft , No the issue isn't resolved yet

Comment: @ThashwinY - Did you get a chance to test the below sample again?
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-teams-authentication/csharp

Could you please verify your configuration settings and permission once and check again?

Comment: Hi @Nivedipa-MSFT have given these 
openid
profile
User.Read
User.ReadBasic.All  
permissions is there anything else to be given?

Comment: We also given only these permissions. Not any additional permissions.

Comment: Can you share the manifest file? @Nivedipa-MSFT

Comment: Here is the manifest.zip. I have removed credentials. Add your credentials and check.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/files/10703987/manifest.zip